# How to run multiple webdriver python programs at the same time?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, multiprocessing

I have 4 Python scripts (3 web drivers and a main script). I would like to open these 3 web drivers at the same time when I run the *mainscript.py*. I used multiprocessing but you can use whatever you want.

Now it opens *bot_1.py* and then *bot_2.py* and then *bot_3.py*.

**bot_1.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Andrei\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
links=['https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emil_Constantinescu','https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traian_B%C4%83sescu','https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_I']
for i in range(len(links)):
    driver.get(links[i])
```

**bot_2.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Andrei\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

links=['https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Lincoln','https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_Churchill','https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mihail_Gorbaciov']
for i in range(len(links)):
    driver.get(links[i])
```

**bot_3.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Andrei\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

links = ['https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriela_Firea', 'https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_Iliescu',
         'https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mihai_Eminescu']
for i in range(len(links)):
    driver.get(links[i])
```

**mainscript.py**

```
import bot_1, bot_2, bot_3
import multiprocessing

for bot in ('bot_1', 'bot_2','bot_3'):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda: __import__(bot))
    p.start()
```

Comment: What is your question/problem? Yes your code's not good. But does it work? Or not?
Or do you need help it better organizing it?

Comment: I would like to run these 3 web drivers at the same time. So I want to make a main script that will do this. Now my main script will open bot_1.py and then bot_2.py and then bot_3.py but I want to open at the same time. So I want to open 3 different chrome browsers with these 3 web drivers that will do their work at the same time. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyTest with the `xdist` extension is one option:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/3.0.0/xdist.html

```
pip install pytest
pip install pytest-xdist
```

Then you run `pytest -n NUM`, where `NUM` is the number of processes (or in your case - webdriver instances) you want to run. I can't exactly remember now, but I think the command above runs all `.py` files in your current folder.

You can also use Behave + behave-parallel.

https://github.com/hugeinc/behave-parallel

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: pytest runs all test_*.py or *_test.py.

Answer (score 3):

This runs in parallel. But it maybe not obvious, because for me it was two overlapping windows. So, i added time.sleep

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from  multiprocessing import Process
#import time

def run(urls):
#    print ("run", urls)
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--no-default-browser-check')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--disable-default-apps')
    options.binary_location = '/opt/chrome-linux.63.0.3239.b.508580/chrome'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
                executable_path='/opt/chromedriver/chromedriver',
                options=options,
                )

    for url in urls:
#        time.sleep(5)
        driver.get(url)
#        print driver.title
    driver.quit()

allurls = [
        ['http://ya.ru', 'http://google.ru'],
        ['https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emil_Constantinescu',
            'https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traian_B%C4%83sescu'],
        ]

processes = []
for urls in allurls:
    p = Process(target=run, args=(urls,))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

Comment: why do you disable all that stuff like gpu, extensions, default apps etc. before starting?

Comment: To free up resources.